# How do I do this using the find function in excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have to find the text "LHS" or "RHS" but in the same column. How do I do this using find function?
I have tried this using Find function and using an OR function as well. But is shows errors

```
Column 1 = Description                  Column 2 = LHS/RHS

FRONT SEAT ASY RHS COMP 4WAY  I need a single formula there that will show RHS/LHS
FRONT SEAT ASY COMP LHS 4WAY  I need a single formula there that will show RHS/LHS
```

Comment: Can you maybe add a sample screenshot? Some sample data, the exact formula you're trying, and the expected output would help make your question clear, thanks!

Comment: I am trying to add a photo but it is not adding it somehow. I have posted a description. Please read it and ask questions if you find it difficult to interpret

Comment: You can upload an image to http://imgur.com and link to it.

Comment: @BigBen Thanks for the editing. Can you provide me with a formula for the question I have posted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Or, in B1, copied down :

```
=MID(A1,MIN(FIND({"RHS","LHS"},A1&"RHSLHS")),3)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps something like the following:

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("RHS ",A2)),"RHS",IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("LHS ",A2)),"LHS","No match"))
```

[image]

Change `SEARCH` to `FIND` to make this case-sensitive.

Another option if you are only allowed to use `LEFT`, `RIGHT`, `MID`, `LEN`, `FIND`, and `TRIM`:

```
=MID(A2,FIND("HS",A2)-1,3)
```

[image]

Comment: I am only allowed to use LEFT
RIGHT
MID
LEN
FIND
TRIM functions

Comment: Then `FIND` only `HS` and then use `MID` to pull it plus the character to the left - see the edit.